# convert RD coordinates to decimal degrees

Tags: gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I want to convert Dutch RD coordinates to longitude and latitude decimal degree coordinates. Example:

```
108519 438598
108518 438578
108517 438578
```

to

```
51.93391 4.71134
51.93382 4.71133
51.93373 4.71131
```

Which packages and what code can I use to apply this on a bigger dataset?

Answer (score 1):

For coordinate conversion one usually uses the proj.4 lib.
Its available for many programming languages, like python, java, c

First you need to find out the projection number as EPSG number.
e.g https://epsg.io/28992
On that page under "export" there is a section for the proj.4 definition of that projection, which gives this string:

```
"+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Using the proj4 lib, you can then convert to WGS84 latitude and longitude, this is the format you want.